# Issue with Forward and backward options in Video player in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, android-videoview

i need to display a video in mobile app which was developed in Xamarin(Andriod) in which the for forward it moving 15 sec ahead and for backward it is moving 5 sec back [image]

Can i get some help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you seems to use the `MediaController` . However , if you want to custom the length of forward and back , you need to create a custom `MediaController` .

#### in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoView1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Button
            android:text="back"
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <Button
            android:text="play"
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <Button
            android:text="forward"
            android:id="@+id/forward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

#### in Activity

```
VideoView videoView;
```

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

       //...


        videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView1);
        videoView.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("xxx.mp4")); // Path of your saved video file.

        videoView.Start();


        Button back = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.back);
        back.Click += Back_Click;

        Button play = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.play);
        play.Click += Play_Click;

        Button forward = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.forward);
        forward.Click += Forward_Click; ;
    }

    private void Forward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoView.SeekTo(videoView.CurrentPosition + 5 * 1000);
    }

    private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (videoView.IsPlaying)
        {
            button.Text = "Play";
            videoView.Pause();

        }
        else
        {
            button.Text = "Pause";
            videoView.Start();
        }

    }

    private void Back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoView.SeekTo(videoView.CurrentPosition-15*1000);
    }
```

And in this way you just need to set the icon of the Buttons as you want .